# Dynamically define a method inside an instance method

Tags: ruby, methods, dynamic

I am working on a project of context-oriented programming in ruby. And I come to this problem:

Suppose that I have a class Klass:

```
class Klass
    def my_method
        proceed
    end
end
```

I also have a proc stored inside a variable `impl`. And `impl` contains `{ puts "it works!" }`.

From somewhere outside Klass, I would like to define a method called `proceed` inside the method `my_method`. So that if a call `Klass.new.my_method`, I get the result `"it works"`.

So the final result should be something like that:

```
class Klass
    def my_method
        def proceed
            puts "it works!"
        end
        proceed
    end
end
```

Or if you have any other idea to make the call of `proceed` inside `my_method` working, it's also good. But the `proceed` of another method (let's say `my_method_2`) isn't the same as `my_method`.
In fact, the `proceed` of `my_method` represent an old version of `my_method`. And the `proceed` of `my_method_2` represent an old version of `my_method_2`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: One can’t store a block in the variable.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Why do you need to define a method that defines a method? Why can't you just define one method or call the correct method in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, I mean a procedure. I edited my question.

In fact, my program modifies a class by adding, removing, updating methods according to a context. And sometimes, a new version of a method use the old version of this method. So the proceed method represent this old version.

Comment: Note that a method definition expression inside a method body may be deprecated in the future in preparation for adding local procedures to Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* **you are doing it wrong!**

There *must* be more robust, elegant and rubyish way to achieve what you want. If you still want to abuse metaprogramming, here you go:

```
class Klass
  def self.proceeds
    @proceeds ||= {}
  end

  def def_proceed
    self.class.proceeds[caller.first[/`.*?'/]] = Proc.new
  end

  def proceed *args
    self.class.proceeds[caller.first[/`.*?'/]].(*args)
  end

  def m_1
    def_proceed { puts 1 }
    proceed
  end

  def m_2
    def_proceed { puts 2 }
    proceed
  end
end

inst = Klass.new

inst.m_1
#⇒ 1
inst.m_2
#⇒ 2
```

What you in fact need, is [`Module#prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) and call `super` from there.

Comment: Indeed. I also wanted to implement something with Hash but got lazy. Your disclaimer is also on point.

Comment: I will look into `prepend`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to construct a hash whose keys are the names of the methods calling `proceed` and whose values are procs that represent the implementations of `proceed` for each method calling it.

```
class Klass
  singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :proceeds)
  @proceeds = {}
  def my_method1(*args)
    proceed(__method__,*args)
  end
  def my_method2(*args)
    proceed(__method__,*args)
  end
  def proceed(m, *args)
    self.class.proceeds[m].call(*args)
  end
end

def define_proceed(m, &block)
  Klass.proceeds[m] = Proc.new &block
end

define_proceed(:my_method1) { |*arr| arr.sum }
define_proceed(:my_method2) { |a,b| "%s-%s" % [a,b] }

k = Klass.new
k.my_method1(1,2,3)        #=> 6
k.my_method2("cat", "dog") #=> "cat-dog"
```